# Accessing files in the Google Cloud Storage from two different google cloud projects

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

Consider the following situation:

- I have two AppEngine projects: A and B
- I have a Cloud Storage bucket with the following ACL:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" ?>
  <AccessControlList>
      <Owner>
          <ID>id-of-the-user-who-created-the-bucket</ID>
      </Owner>
      <Entries>
          <Entry>
              <Scope type="UserByEmail">
                  <EmailAddress>app-A-service-account-name</EmailAddress>
              </Scope>
              <Permission>FULL_CONTROL</Permission>
          </Entry>
          <Entry>
              <Scope type="UserByEmail">
                  <EmailAddress>app-B-service-account-name</EmailAddress>
              </Scope>
              <Permission>FULL_CONTROL</Permission>
          </Entry>
      </Entries>
  </AccessControlList>
  ```
- My GAE applications are written in Python and they are using [GCS Client Library](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/)

**Now, here is what I want to achieve**: I want application A to create files inside the bucket and then application B to read them.

At first I tried to simply create a file with `cloudstorage.open(file_name, 'w')` and then read its status with `cloudstorage.stat(file_name, 'r')`, but this way I end up with the following error while reading:

```
ForbiddenError at /.../
Expect status [200] from Google Storage. But got status 403.
```

(The error message provides also request/response information: path, headers, body and extra info. Please let me know if you think they may be helpful in solving this case)

Then I started experimenting with ACLs by setting the [`x-googl-acl`](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/reference-headers#xgoogacl) option while creating a file, for example:

```
cloudstorage.open(file_name, 'w', options={'x-goog-acl': 'authenticated-read'})
```

Although ACLs work as intended, none of the available options seem to fit my requirements:

- `private` - only the bucket owner has the access, B cannot read
- `public-read` - file is accessible by anonymous users, unacceptable
- `public-read-write` - same as above
- `authenticated-read` - everyone with authenticated account is able to read (even people who are not part of the project), so it's no different than the previous option
- `bucket-owner-read` - seems perfect, but it turns out that "the bucket owner" is NOT the user who was set as "owner" through the Cloud Console, but the user who created the bucket
- `bucket-owner-full-control` - same as above

It looks like I ran out of options, but I can't believe that such a simple thing cannot be achieved with the Cloud Storage. The only solution that comes to my mind is changing system's architecture, but I would like to avoid it. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the accessor Service Accounts (e.g. app1@appspot.gserviceaccount.com or 1234567890-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com for compute engine) as member with 'Editor' permission on project with the GCS bucket to use. This can be done in IAM page of the project that owns the bucket:
https://console.developers.google.com/iam-admin/iam/project?project=app1

Comment: Could you post how that would look like in the ACL?

Comment: Important note: the service account has to be added to the whole project, not just the storage bucket (didn't work for me at least)