# Access Google Cloud Storage object in a project that I don't belong to

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-api-python-client

There is a GCP project that contains a bucket that I have read and write permissions to, but I don't know the name of the project nor am I part of the project. None of the contents of this bucket are public.

I have successfully authenticated my user locally using `gcloud auth application-default login`.

I can successfully download from this bucket using `gsutil cat gs://BUCKET/PATH`.

However, if I use the `google.cloud.storage` Python API, it fails at the point of identifying the project, presumably because I don't have access to the project itself:

```py
from google.cloud import storage
client = storage.Client()
storage.Blob.from_string("gs://BUCKET/PATH", client=client).download_as_text()
```

> The billing account for the owning project is disabled in state closed: ('Request failed with status code', 403, 'Expected one of', <HTTPStatus.OK: 200>, <HTTPStatus.PARTIAL_CONTENT: 206>)

I can't use `storage.Client.create_anonymous_client()` since this is only relevant for public buckets, but I suspect that I could fix this by changing the `credentials` argument to `Client()`.

Can anyone help me download the file from Google Cloud in this case?

Comment: You can use your own project, not the Bucket project. It's for the quotas and API calls limits/billing, no matter at which project the bucket belong to.

Comment: This same error occurs when I specify a project. I believe it's already using the project based on my environment.

Comment: Have you checked this [thread1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24738811/18265570) & [thread2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36845345/18265570)?

Answer (score 0):

If you have permission, you can find the project number for a given bucket with the [bucket get](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/buckets/get) API call. See [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/getting-bucket-size-and-metadata#display-bucket-properties) for how to do it with various client libraries.